# How do I load a QImage from a file in Qt6? My Qt5 method generates errors

Tags: qt

I'm new to Qt6.  In Qt6.4.3, I'm writing a simple console app in c++ to load a .jpg file into a QImage object.  On my Ubuntu 6.22.04 machine, I'm getting the following error:
"/main.cpp:40: undefined reference to `QImage::load(QString const&, char const*)'"
I have the following in my includes:

```
    #include <QtGui/QImage>
```

I declare the following as 3 consecutive lines:

```
    QString filename="<fullpath>.JPG";
    QImage img;
    img.load(filename, "JPG");
```

I'm using cmake, but don't know whether that's relevant.  Using Qt Creator 9.0.2.  This approach used to work well in Qt5.
I know someone's gonna call me an idiot or a lazy idiot or tell me to RTFM, so go ahead.  Get it out of your system, but then please give me some *useful* advice.

Tried the statements above, attempted a build, and got the error shown above.  I was expecting a QImage object returned stuffed with the .jpeg image I requested.  My fullpath looks similar to "/mnt//Project/testme/blahblah.JPG".  The path is correct with correct case and slashes.  As I said this worked in Qt5.15. Figure I'm missing something stupid, but after spending all day searching the web, I haven't found the answer.

Comment: "undefined reference to" is a linking error not a compiling error. The problem is going to be something with how your CMakeLists file is doing the linking.

Comment: Show the cmakelists.txt

Comment: Thank you, jwezorek!  I thought cmake might be the issue.  Coming from  5.15 I've always been a qmake boy.  Your suggestion was golden, and I really appreciate it!  Here are the MakeLists edits that did it for me:
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui)
add_executable(untitled37
  main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(untitled37 Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Gui)

Comment: Please create a [MCVE], which I think in this case should include CMakeLists.txt (unless you are using default created by Qt Creator new project wizard), and main.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in your CMakeLists.txt. You are missing the Qt Gui module, which is needed for QImage.

Below is working code, tested on Windows and Qt 6.4.

---

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(untitled VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Gui REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(appuntitled
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(appuntitled
    PRIVATE Qt6::Gui)
```

---

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QImage>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QImage img;
    qDebug() << img.size();
    img.load("C:/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/qbs/share/qbs/examples/compiled-qml/cheese.jpg");
    qDebug() << img.size();

    return img.isNull() ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

---

Application Output shown by Qt Creator:

```
13:32:10: Starting C:\Users\hyde\Qt\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_6_4_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\appuntitled.exe...
QSize(0, 0)
QSize(94, 94)
13:32:10: C:\Users\hyde\Qt\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_6_4_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\appuntitled.exe exited with code 0
```